# OpenSUSE: Installation of packages failed

Tags: opensuse

I'm traying to install openSuse 15.2 (openSUSE-Leap-15.2-DVD-x86_64) in Virtualbox. But all the time I get an error after an error that packages can not be installed:

[image]

Always the same `Digest mismatch`:
[image]

I tired the DVD and NET Iso image several times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please click on "show details" and share that here.

Comment: Added a additional screenshot with the error "Disgest mismatch"

Comment: Which DVD ISO are you installing from? There might be a temporary issue with the repositories.

Comment: openSUSE-Leap-15.2-DVD-x86_64

Comment: Did you compare the checksum of the ISO? If there's a repo problem it would only affect network installation, the DVD should work. except if you enabled updates during the install. I was able to install 15.2 just last week, so I'm not sure what's going on there.